# memory management impact on setting objects to null in finally

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

```
public void func1()
{    
    object obj= null;
    try
    {
             obj=new object();
    }
    finally
    {
             obj = null;
    }
}
```

**is there any advantage of assigning null to a reference in finally block in regards of memory management of large objects?**

Comment: I can't find any concern between your question and the title!

Comment: title is my mistake. the question above is my original question. how can I change the title now?

Comment: Use **edit** button below the question.

Comment: You need to explicit more which type of object you are talking about.
If the code stay this way, the null assignment it's not usefull.

We need the scope of the object (how much will exist) and some way to understand the property of the object (how much memory will use, will have access to unmanaged resources, implements idisposable...)

Comment: Have a look at [Large object heap](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8015302/706456) question

Comment: Bujutsu -  I've modified the question. I hope that answer the scope. I'm concerned about large objects . How does  unmanaged resources, implements idisposable impact here?

Comment: oleksii - that doesn't answer my question. LOH are not cleared from heap on first garbage collection  but i've read somewhere that assigning null to such references will help in garbage collection.

Comment: @Alok - "assigning null to such references will help in garbage collection." - how? When you leave the scope of `func1`, then the object referenced by `obj` is no longer reachable and a candidate for garbage collection (assuming no passing of a reference to the object to the outside). Setting the variable `obj` to `null` before the end of the method removes the reference to the actual object *maybe* a few nanoseconds earlier. So in the case that the GC runs between `obj = null;` and end of method you *might* have an ever so slight advantage.

Comment: The GC runs whenever it decides to run. Especially, when memory gets scarce. So setting a variable to `null` is a micro optimization at best (if at all), and should only be done if you have proof (via memory profiler) that there is an actual memory problem which is solved by this. On the other hand, if the actual object you work with implements [IDisposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/fs2xkftw.aspx), then you should be [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/yh598w02.aspx) a different approach anyways.

Comment: @Coark - I've read that thing in a MSDN article that in practical by using this memory is released early. I don't have a ref to that article now. But If in my example obj is property of a class not a variable in func1, then what would be your ans?

Comment: @Alok - then that would count as passing a reference to the outside (of the scope the object was created in) and I'd wholeheartedly agree with the excellent answer Lasse provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's deal with the explicit and implicit questions here.

**Q:** First and foremost, is there a point in assigning `null` to a local variable when you're done with it?

**A:** No, none at all. When compiled with optimizations and not running under a debugger, the JITter knows the segment of the code where a variable is in use and will automatically stop considering it a root when you've passed that segment. In other words, if you assign something to a variable, and then at some point never again read from it, it may be collected even if you don't explicitly set it to `null`.

So your example can safely be written as:

```
public void func1()
{    
    object obj = new object();
    // implied more code here
}
```

If no code in the "implied more code here" ever accesses the `obj` variable, it is no longer considered a root.

Note that this changes if running in a non-optimized assembly, or if you hook up a debugger to the process. In that case the scope of variables is artificially extended until the end of their scope to make it easier to debug.

---

**Q:** Secondly, what about fields in the surrounding class?

**A:** Here it can definitely make a difference.

If the object surrounding your method is kept alive for an extended period of time, and the need for the contents of a field has gone, then yes, setting the field to `null` will make the old object it referenced eligible for collection.

So this code might have merit:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private object obj;

    public void func1()
    {    
        try
        {
             obj=new object();
             // implied more code here
        }
        finally
        {
             obj = null;
        }
    }
}
```

But then, why are you doing it like this? You should instead strive to write cleaner code that doesn't rely on surrounding state. In the above code you should instead refactor the "implied more code here" to be passed in the object to use, and remove the global field.

Obviously, if you can't do that, then yes, setting the field to `null` as soon as its object reference is no longer needed is a good idea.

---

Fun experiment, if you run the below code in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) with optimizations on, what do you expect the output to be?

```
void Main()
{
    var s = new Scary();
    s.Test();
}

public class Scary
{
    public Scary()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(".ctor");
    }

    ~Scary()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("finalizer");
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("starting test");
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
        Console.WriteLine("ending test");
    }
}
```

Answer (mouseover to show when you think you've got it):

> .ctor
>  starting test
>  finalizer
>  ending test

Explanation:

> Since the implicit `this` parameter to an instance method is never used inside the method, the object surrounding the method is collected, even if the method is currently running.